# ASP.NET Core rate limiting errors in only one route from the API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm developing an API with ASP.NET Core without identity and would like to limit the number of failed requests within the login route.

I can't post the full code but the structure that I'm using is like this:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<AuthViewModel>> Login([FromBody] UserLoginViewModel userLoginVm)
{
    var auth = await service.Login(userLoginVm);
    if (auth == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Wrong login.");
    }

    return Ok(auth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should explain your goal.

Are you want to limit login requests by `Username` or `IP`?

If you want to limit request by `IP` you can use [`AspNetCoreRateLimiter`](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/) package to limit your `API` based on [`IP`](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/IpRateLimitMiddleware#setup) or [`ClientId`](https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/ClientRateLimitMiddleware#setup)

Another option is [Redis INCR](https://redis.io/commands/INCR). by `INCR` every time that you check the username and password you can call the `INCR` method and it returns an `integer` value that shows to you the count of the method call by a `key`.

> Redis key can be like this: `Username_IP_API`

and if Redis's result is more than your limitation you can block the request.

---

If you are using `AspNetCoreIdentity` you can enable lock after max failed access attempt:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(identityOptions =>
            {
                //Lockout Settings
                identityOptions.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                identityOptions.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                identityOptions.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
            })
```